# Wave Analytic Official User Group

Tags: analytics-cloud, einstein-analytics

I tried to find out for Wave analytic official user group but unable. Not sure is there any group or not. Do you have any info on this please ?

Comment: here's one in success community that I know : https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009MBP

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I'd upvote if you'd post that as an answer rather than as a comment :-)

Comment: thx @SamuelDeRycke .. Done.. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Here's the [Official: Wave - Analytics Cloud Group](https://success.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F9300000009MBP) in Success Community

you can ask your wave related questions there with #AskTheACExperts and probably cc : @[Lauren Peterson] from Salesforce